# How to combine two sql queries? [for the filter]

Tags: mysql, sql

I have tables

**labels**

```
id INT A_I
id_user INT
id_label INT
```

**labels_data**

```
id INT A_I
label VARCHAR(10)
name VARCHAR(30)
```

**tasks**

```
id INT A_I
name VARCHAR(30)
value VARCHAR(1000)
```

And i want add entry to the table named **tasks** and I want add 3-4 entries to the table named **labels**. How I can do it and can i do it in one query??

Thanks...

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/) See [ask advice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice), please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are doing this directly through queries, then you will need one query for each row you are inserting to a table. So this will be one Insert to `Tasks` and 3-4 inserts to `labels`.

See the mysql manual for [Insert syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html).

Comment: I use sqlalchemy. That is only option?